# How to create multi color rows on JTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I built a form with Netbeans JFrame Form, I mean from netbeanse itself by right click on the project and then New and then JFrame Form. Also I use a Jtable by dragging that on the form. Now in my code I want to colorize the rows on Jtable. I have seen some idea from https://coderanch.com/t/476777/java/Color-Row-JTable But all the direction which I have seen is about overriding Jatble. My problem is In my program netbeans it self does the code in declaration JFrame element from where I can override the code or specifically in this case how can I make the rows colorized ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already put the JTable in the JFrame you can right click on it and then chose ***Customize Code***.

It will present you a window where some code is written. You can add custom code on the white lines, **not the gray ones** unless you want to change an already defined property.

Remember though that you should implement your custom cell renderer first.

In case you want to change an already defined property of the JTable, you have to first change the ***Default Code*** drop down menu on the left of the property to ***custom creation***.

I hope this will help you out.